# Laptop loses internet connection when changing to static IP address

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I'm trying to set up a static IP connection to the WiFi for my old gaming laptop so I can use it as a server.

I change the IP connection via control panel etc. I change it to the following:

- IP address: 192.168.1.12
- Subnet Mask: 255. 255. 255. 0
- Default Gateway: 192.168.1.10
- Preferred DNS server: 8.8.8.8
- Alternative DNS server: 8.8.4.4

When I close it I lose the connection to the internet. The following is my `IPconfig` after I've set the static IP address and run `/release` and `/renew`:

```
C:\Users\slbro>ipconfig
Windows IP Configuration
Ethernet adapter Ethernet:
   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : fdaa:bbcc:ddee:0:34e0:e8a7:412d:9a1c
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : fdaa:bbcc:ddee:0:1135:1bc8:25fa:2e8e
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::a301:b3b5:f26c:84f1%14
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.12
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.10

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

When I switch it back to automatically assigning IP addresses, my internet connection is restored.

Here's the `IPconfig /all` once I return to auto:

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : DESKTOP-1TQ6IJ0
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : lan

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : D4-81-D7-AE-2E-4D
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : TAP-NordVPN Windows Adapter V9
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-FF-8C-B2-13-C6
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 3C-F8-62-E6-3D-7D
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 4:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 3E-F8-62-E6-3D-7C
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 3C-F8-62-E6-3D-80
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : lan
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 3C-F8-62-E6-3D-7C
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : fdaa:bbcc:ddee:0:34e0:e8a7:412d:9a1c(Preferred)
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : fdaa:bbcc:ddee:0:38a6:b0cc:4296:fb73(Preferred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::a301:b3b5:f26c:84f1%14(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.20(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 25 April 2023 22:55:54
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 26 April 2023 22:55:54
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 87881826
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-20-88-A0-08-D4-81-D7-AE-2E-4D
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I can look at?

Comment: Is .12 inside your DHCP Pool? That is, did your make your DHCP Pool smaller than the complete .1 subnet range?   Why is your gateway .10?  It is normally .1. It might be correct and I am just asking.

Comment: What result do you get from `ipconfig` after you have set the static configuration?

Comment: When you say you lose connection to the Internet, do you get a positive result with `ping 8.8.8.8`? What about `ping google.com`? This is about partitioning the problem between network (no ping responses at all) and DNS (first works, second fails)

Comment: @roaima- The IP config that I copied in my post is after setting it as static configuration

Comment: @roaima I just tried pinging google.com and "ping request could not find host google.com". And I also tried 8.8.8.8 and "ping:@ transmit failed. general failure"

Comment: Can you answer the questions I asked please?

Comment: If the `ipconfig` output is after you've set the static IP address, put the setting back to DHCP and show us the same output. There will be a difference in the settings.

Comment: Will do John. Just working my way up :)

Comment: @John To be honest I'm not 100%^ sure how to find out what the pool range is. I'm just looking into it now. Still learning.

Comment: Open your router config and look at the LAN setup section. The DHCP range will show there.

Comment: Most likely your default gateway is wrong and it should be 192.168.1.1 or possibly 192.168.1.254. Set it back to DHCP and then do the ipconfig /all to see what DHCP gives you. You should use the SAME settings for a static config.
Better approach is to leave the laptop on DHCP but let the router give it a DHCP reservation so it hands out the same ip-address to the laptop every time. That way the router knows what it has given to the laptop and you avoid the problem that the router may think the static address is free to give to another device.

Comment: Default gateweay (aka, "the router") is indeed 192.168.1.1. Your 2nd ipconfig output proves that.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I'll update that then

Comment: I think that's sorted it out. So is it better to have the reserved ip address via the router rather than a static IP address. Does it always use the reserved address?

Comment: @John, You were right as well, I was within the DHCP range, so I've changed that as well

Comment: If your router support DCHP Reservations use that instead of a static IP. Works better

Comment: Thanks so much. I've been going round in circles with this.

Comment: I posted an answer for you to consider.

Comment: the gateway address on your network is `192.168.1.1` which is why DHCP sets this. When you set it to 192.168.1.10 of course the computer no longer sees the gateway at that address

Answer (score 2):

For you specifically, when creating a static configuration, your default gateway should be set to 192.168.1.1, as should your DNS server. Ideally you should ensure your static IP address is outside the DHCP range so that the DHCP server can't allocate "your" IP address elsewhere.

In general, when creating a static configuration, use the values provided through DHCP as your starting point.

The better option for a machine that isn't a server and isn't intended to be on 24x7 is to create a reservation assignment in the DHCP server. (Sometimes this is called a sticky address.) This lets your machine still use DHCP to get its settings but the DHCP server guarantees always to assign you the same nominated address.

Answer (score 0):

Based on all comments and your responses, I suggest the following:

1. If you are using Static IP, make sure the router has a DHCP section and then everything else is available for Static. Use your Router Login and go to the LAN setup page. Find out what your DCHP range is.  I use .100 to .254 and for my own piece of mind, I keep Static IP addresses below .050. Apple iPhones can be misbehaved so I used to keep them Static. Now I use DCHP Reservation for iPhones.
2. We have already established that your router gateway should be (here) 192.168.1.1 . You were using 192.168.1.10 and that will not work . DNS Servers for me are what the ISP provides and I use these. This is a router setting and then Static can be set for that on a workstation.
3. If your router support DHCP Reservation, use this and where workstations have their Network MAC address in the Reservation table, provide a DHCP address in the Reservation table (keep a section of DHCP in the router for this). Then for the Workstation, use DHCP automatic settings and you will get the same IP all the time which will work in the Server you are trying to set up.

These are the basic goals you should work toward.